# How to Perform "Vertical Privilege Escalation" testing using ZAP?

Tags: security, testing, zap

I need to perform "Vertical Privilege Escalation" Testing Using ZAP. Please help me how to active this i am currently using OWASP ZAP 2.6.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the option Access Control Testing add-on: https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-extensions/wiki/HelpAddonsAccessControlConcepts